# Create temporary table as select union all not working in MySQL 5.6.17 but works on MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date_range AS (
    SELECT 1 AS `from`, 5 AS `to`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 15
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, 20
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 21, 25
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 26, 100
);
```

but when I remove all the union all, it works.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date_range AS (
    SELECT 1 AS `from`, 5 AS `to`
);
```

In MySQL 8, it is working fine, but I have to recode it to work on MySQL 5 so I created this:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date_range(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `from` INT NULL,
    `to` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tmp_date_range (`from`, `to`)
SELECT 1 AS `from`, 5 AS `to`
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 15
UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 20
UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 25
UNION ALL
SELECT 26, 100;
```

this is the error code: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL         SELECT 6, 10         UNION ALL         SELECT 11, 15         U' at line 17

Comment: Must work. See for misprint or excess non-printable char.

Comment: This might be a strange idea but can you try to do the `INSERT` in one line instead? Something [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=16e3c6ba93716f6c256bfd762c6ca0b6)?

Comment: @Akina

I tried everything but this does not work in MySQL 5, only in MySQL 8

`
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date_range AS (
    SELECT 1 AS `from`, 5 AS `to`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 10
);
`

Comment: @FaNo_FN that code works in mysql 5 and 8, I just separated it per line so it is much easier to read.

Comment: Works in 5.5 and 5.6: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&rdbms2=mysql_5.5&fiddle=7a36348c5e42eab20d7e0d8a0b445540). May try another versions - must work, no reason for not to work. PS. `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` not needed in `AS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading the answer from @FaNo_FN, this is working too:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date_range AS select * from (
    SELECT 1 AS `from`, 5 AS `to`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 15
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, 20
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 21, 25
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 26, 100
) x;
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=dae1611b4e654f3ff4eb44faefd79f67)

Comment: I'll accept this answer as the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MySQL version 5.7 and below will return error if you run a `SELECT` with `UNION` enclosed with a single pair of *parentheses*`()`.

For example, in MySQL 5.7 and below, this query will run successfully:

```
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2;
```

This query will also run successfully:

```
(SELECT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT 2);
```

This query will return error:

```
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2);

Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
        check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
         right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL SELECT 2)' at line 1
```

Hence, due to that limitation this query in older MySQL version will return error:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date_range;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date_range AS (  <--- because of this parenthesis 
    SELECT 1 AS `from`, 5 AS `to`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 15
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, 20
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 21, 25
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 26, 100
) <--- because of this parenthesis 
;
```

Instead if you remove the parentheses, it should work. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c3bca05f9f0bdbf9f4e1f343c68c7417)

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation that explains exactly why it behaves like that but there is a documentation about [union in MySQL v8 vs 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-8-0-versus-5-7).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now I know it's because of the parenthesis.